# Get value of django model field

Tags: python, django

I have two classes in my model :

```
class Zones(models.Model):
    zone = models.CharField(max_length=20)
def __str__(self):
    return self.zone


class Weight(models.Model):
   weight=models.FloatField(default=0)
   rate = models.FloatField(null=True)
   zones = models.ForeignKey(Zones, null=True)
def __str__(self):
    return str(self.weight)
```

Is it possible to get zone of a given particular rate with queryset?

I dont want all the zones related to that weight but I want only the zone that is related to some particular weight and rate which will be unique.

Answer (score 0):

Ya, you should. Just do like this,

```
w = Weight.objects.filter(rate=2.99)
print [i.zones.zone for i in w]
```

Comment: It is giving all the zones related to that weight but I want only the zone that is related to some particular weight and rate which will be unique.

Comment: @AnmolGulati post a sample data.

Answer (score 0):

You can get list of the zone by given query.

```
zones = Weight.objects.filter(rate=rate_value).value_list('zones')
```

Answer (score 0):

> I dont want all the zones related to that weight but I want only the
>   zone that is related to some particular weight and rate which will be
>   unique.

For uniqueness, it would be better to give the `unique_together` condition to the `Meta` class of the model like

```
class Weight(models.Model):
   weight=models.FloatField(default=0)
   rate = models.FloatField(null=True)
   zones = models.ForeignKey(Zones, null=True)

   def __str__(self):
      return str(self.weight)

   class Meta:
      unique_together=(('weight', 'rate',))
```

then making sure that the query result would be one and only one, you can use the model objects' `get` method.

```
related_zone = Weight.objects.get(weight=WEIGHT, rate=RATE).zones
```

Answer (score 0):

```
zones = Weight.objects.filter(rate=rate_value).values('zones', 'rates', 'weight')
```